# No R interpreter defined: Many R related features like combination, code checking and help won't be available

Tags: pycharm, python-3.6

I am newbie to pycharm , I have installed this and everytime I got an error when I created a new project , K am not able to find the solution  plz help me out .

[ No R interpreter defined. Many R related features like completion, code checking and help won't be available.You can set an interpreter under Preference->Languages->R ]

I tried to fix this as mentioned but I am not able to find where is "preference" .

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-preferences-dialog.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For someone who looking solution for this, this is because when you install pycharm, you select to install R plugin but you don't have R interpreter in your machine. Solution is:

1. Install R interpreter as explained by @sagarsys
2. In Idea 2018 (Ubuntu), go to: `File -> Setting`. Looking for "plugin" in the vertical tab, and then [uncheck "R language Support"](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000754610-What-to-do-when-an-error-occurs-No-R-interpreter-is-defined-a-function-associated-with-R-as-the-end-check-the-code-and-help-will-not-be-available-You-can-set-interpreter-in-Settings-Languages-R-?page=1#community_comment_360000095359). Or if you don't need R, just uninstall it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the R-Project files from Berkley.

Go to: https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu

Download and install the package which corresponds to your OS. You are going to want the base distro.

Go back to your new project in PyCharm and open File->Settings

Select "Languages & Frameworks" then "R-Language"

You will add the location of the Rgui.exe file now installed on your PC.  (On Windows, this is typically "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64\Rgui.exe"). You will want to select either x32 or x64 depending on your OS.

The program will proceed to update "Skeletons" and you should be good to go.

Comment: I do not have the option "R-Language" @sagarsys

Comment: Same here. Also, the link https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu does not work - displays some Red Hat Linux Test page saying the site is down.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in Python and you are getting such error, Then this may be due to adding of the plugin **R Language Support** during installation of JetBrains Pycharm.

So, to remove this error you need to go to **settings->plugins->Installed**

There you can select The R Language Support plugin and uninstall that plugin